# Android RelativeLayout Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-layout

I have a class which extends `RelativeLayout` and in this class I create a `Thread`. My custom `RelativeLayout` is now used in a `ListView`.

Now my problem. I start the `Thread` after instantiation of my class. Now the user scrolled the `ListView` very fast. Where can I stop my `Thread`, because if my custom `RelativeLayout` is out of scope it won't be `GC`ed because the `Thread` is still there.

Here a stub of my code...

```
private Thread mThread;

public class MyLayout() extends RelativeLayout {

    public MyLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mThread = new Thread(new Runnable...);
        mThread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your view is being used in each list item, then in your adapter you can stop the thread when the view passed to getView() is non-null, meaning it is being recycled.